# create add function for calculator android

Tags: java, android

I need to create a calculator in Android. I need to create a `plus` function to add to numbers (integers). Here is my code. I also need to create other functions, like for subtraction.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,plus,minus,mul,divide,equal;
    TextView textView;
    String currentDisplayedInput="";
    private String inputToBeParsed = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
        equal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.equal);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentDisplayedInput += "1";
                //inputToBeParsed += "1";
                textView.setText(currentDisplayedInput);

            }
        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentDisplayedInput += "2";
                //inputToBeParsed += "1";
                textView.setText(currentDisplayedInput);

            }
        });

        equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

All I need to do is to when I click `1 + 1`, the `TextView` should show the result `2`.

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do a simple calculator in Android? How to do it using Buttons and single edit text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280263/how-do-a-simple-calculator-in-android-how-to-do-it-using-buttons-and-single-edi)

Comment: i am not using edit text. i am using textview to show the result

Comment: Does that matter? Both have a setText method

Comment: You would think a calculator is simple to write, but it really isn't... Your code doesn't handle `1+1`, all it does is input `1` and `2`. And if you press the plus button, do you add a `+` symbol? Java doesn't have a single method to "evaluate math expressions"